# d3.js: add elements according to data-attribute value

Tags: d3.js

I simplified example as much as possible. I have data.csv file and want to create elements as below (Result). Is there some elegant way? Thank you.

Data (data.csv):

```
id, name, value
1, fruits, apple
2, fruits, pear
3, fruits, strawberry
4, vegetables, carrot
5, vegetables, celery
...
```

Result:

```
    <g class="groups" id="fruits">
      <circle class="some" id="apple"/>
      <circle class="some" id="pear"/>
      <circle class="some" id="strawberry"/>
      ...
    </g>
    <g class="groups" id="vegetables">
      <circle class="some" id="carrot">
      <circle class="some" id="celery">
      ...
    </g>
```

I tried something like this:

```
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
    var svg = ...
    var groups = svg.selectAll(".groups")
                  .data(data)
                  .enter().append("g")
                  .attr("class", "groups")
                  .attr("id", function(d) { return d.name; });

        groups.selectAll(".some")
        .data(data, function(d) { return d.id; })
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "some")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.value; });
   });
```

But it selects all lines. I don't know how to select and enter only lines with the same name as parent g element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [`nest` operator](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_nest) for this:

```
var byName = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.name; })
                      .entries(data);
var groups = svg.selectAll(".groups").data(byName)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "groups")
                .attr("id", function(d) { return d.key; });
var circles = groups.selectAll(".some")
                    .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
                    .enter().append("circle")
                    .attr("class", "some")
                    .attr("id", function(d) { return d.value; });
```

Comment: It works, thank you. What if I want to load data about circles from different file, e.g. data2?

Comment: Same thing. You may need to adjust the attribute names, but the principle is the same.

Comment: It looked like works, but after some experiments I realized that it doesn't. When I copy-pasted and tried your example, then result was different. g elements are alright, but there is only one circle in each of them (apple).

Comment: Do you have a complete example somewhere?

Comment: Ok, stupid typo -- the first argument to the second `.data()` call should be the function... I'll fix this in the answer.